# Need a good example of LinqDataSource in code, not markup

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq, linq-to-sql, linqdatasource

Anyone have a good example of setting up a LinqDataSource entirely in code?  I don't need help writing the LINQ query.  I just need help setting up the flow of the code.  The reason I want to do it in code is because the complexity of the query I need goes beyond the capabilities of the LinqDataSource wizard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, can you specify what you mean by *setting up*? This is an example of how to create a `LinqDataSource` and prepare it for use:

```
LinqDataSource source = new LinqDataSource();
source.ContextTypeName = "MyDataContext";
source.TableName = "MyTable";
source.Select = "new (Id As MyId, Name As MyName)";
source.Where = "Id > 1";
```

To construct the query programatically instead, you can do this:

```
LinqDataSource source = new LinqDataSource();
source.ContextTypeName = "MyDataContext";
source.Selecting += source_Selecting;
...
void source_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = from number in numbers where number > 1 select number;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to write a full linq query (not having to specify a TableName property, etc.)  I would consider just writing a linq query and using the result as the datasource for my control and binding to it, but I want to take advantage of the paging/sorting that LinqDataSource has.

Comment: I've added an example of a custom query.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://johanleino.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!6BE273C70C45B5D1!328.entry) was made in relation SharePoint and the SPGridView but it might help you.